# Center a Text in terminal

Tags: sh, centering, variable-expansion

I write the follow script, to print one name to the center of my terminal. In the last command, when i use numbers, everything is ok. However, when i use variables x_center and y_center i have a trouble...

```
#!/bin/sh
`clear`

num_lines=`tput lines`
num_cols=`tput cols`

echo "Enter your Name: "
read name

length_name=`echo $name | wc -c `
length_name=`expr $length_name - 1`

offset=`expr $length_name / 2`
x_center=`expr $num_lines / 2`
y_center=`expr $num_cols / 2`
y_center=`expr $offset + $x_center`

printf "%s = %d, %s = %d\n" "X" "$x_center" "Y" "$y_center"

echo -n "\033[$x_center;$y_centerf" $name
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `bash` when you seem to avoid many of the useful features that it offers like shell arithmetic and string length functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That last line looks as if it was intended to move the cursor:

```
echo -n "\033[$x_center;$y_centerf" $name
```

However, it will not because this fragment `$y_centerf` is not defined, and does not end with the appropriate *final character* of the control sequence.  Rather than do this, one can do

```
tput cup $x_center $y_center
echo "$name"
```

The `cup` means "cursor position", and can be found in the [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual page.  `CUP` likewise can be found in *[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)*.  The fragment indicated likely was copied from some example using the similar `HVP`:

```
CSI Ps ; Ps f
      Horizontal and Vertical Position [row;column] (default =
      [1,1]) (HVP).
```

Curly braces could repair it, e.g., `${y_center}f`), but (a) `HVP` is less common than `CUP` and (b) using hard-coded escapes when `tput` is already working is problematic.